# Mining Association rules from a data warehouse and a transactional database

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommender-system, association-rules, market-basket-analysis

I wonder if it is possible to perform market basket analysis to extract the association rules from a data warehouse and a transactional database in the same time to predict the future purchases of a specific user?

Comment: I mean by using historical data from a data warehouse and a transactional database, can we extract the valuable association rules to make a personalized content for a user. for example: if a user bought a pc, in 2 years, he would likely buy a pc battery. [focusing on TIME dimension]